# Using a Linked List to sort data from a text file

Tags: java, sorting, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use a linked list to sort out data from a text file and then rewrite it in numerical order to another pre-existing text file.
I keep getting a nullpointer exception, though.
Can someone please look over my code and tell me what is missing?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class Sort{

public static void main(String[] args){

    String infileName=args[0];
    String outfileName=args[1];


    try{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(infileName))));
    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(outfileName))));




    Node linkedList=new Node();
    //linkedList.value=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String tempS=br.readLine();
    while(tempS!=null){
        tempS=br.readLine();
        Node tempNode=new Node();
        linkedList=tempNode;
        tempNode.value=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        tempNode.next=linkedList;
        bw.write(tempNode.next+"\n");


    }

    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

    }catch(IOException ioe){ioe.getMessage();}
}
}


class Node{
    Double value;
    Node next=null;
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise? There are methods within the Java API for achieving this...

Comment: And reformat the code.

Comment: stack-trace please ...

Comment: Do you have to write your own linked list? Is there any reason you're not using `Scanner`? Also you probably want to use the `import java.io.*` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing `linkedList` assignment every new line. This isn't LinkedList, you should only create the LinkedList and then .Add to it the new node.

Remove `linkedList=tempNode;` from the loop. And add `tempNode` only to the latest `node.next` with something like `lastNode.next = tempNode;`

Answer (score 0):

Within the while loop it looks like you are reading a line into tempS, but when you initialize the tempNode you are reading another line (which might let you run off the end of the file, based on a generalized guess)--

you are then calling parseDouble on that second readLine --

if that second readLine is pulling back nothing, then parseDouble will throw a nullPointerException as you have found.

if you change it to use tempS you still won't be safe since you are reading tempS AFTER the while loop checks for nullity.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

hopefully that helps =)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to NOT use a linked list for sorting if you intend to use lexicographical sorting (Read: Collections.sort()). This will take your sort from O(nlog(n)) to O(n^2 * log(N)). Meaning a factor of N more. This is because the access time of any element in a LinkedList is O(N).

Alternatively, use an ArrayList or use a bucket-style sort like a Trie + LL. ArrayList + stand java stuff will be much faster to implement